# Create a Second Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I have started playing with Android studio.  I cannot figure out how to add a second activity to my project.  I know this is in an early beta phase, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this could make up a considerable question.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a second Java file which extends the Activity Base class and add a reference in your AndroidManifest.xml